# Setting the number of edges in igraph_erdos_renyi_game c++

Tags: c++, social-networking, igraph

I would like to create a directed network graph using igraph c++ in which each node is randomly connected to exactly n other distinct nodes in the network (i.e. excluding connections to itself, and loops/multiple edges to the same loop). I was thinking of using the method `igraph_erdos_renyi_game`, but for some reason I do not get the desired degree distribution. In particular, if I set the arguments like this:

```
igraph_erdos_renyi_game(&g, IGRAPH_ERDOS_RENYI_GNM, n, m, true, false);
```

with n = 5, m = 1, I get this Adjacency Matrix (e.g.):

```
0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

1 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0
```

If I use `igraph_k_regular_game(&g, n, m, true, false)` instead, I get exactly the desired outcome, namely (e.g.):

```
0 0 0 0 1

1 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 1

0 1 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 0
```

So to summarize, I would like for each node to have 1 edge to n randomly selected agents. Am I misinterpreting the way the Erdos-Renyi method works, or am I passing the wrong arguments?

Comment: `m` is the total number of edges in `erdos_renyi_game()`. So just use `k_regular_game()`, it does exactly what you want.

Comment: @GaborCsardi, do you mind putting that comment as an answer? Niccola, do you mind answering that in order to mark that question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m` is the total number of edges `in erdos_renyi_game()`. So just use `k_regular_game()`, it does exactly what you want.

Comment: any chance you can have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182255/perform-union-of-graphs-based-on-vertex-names-python-igraph)? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Antoine I don't have much to do with Python, sorry. Maybe try the igraph-help mailing list.