# Perform union of graphs based on vertex names Python igraph

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, graph, igraph

This issue has been filed on [github](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/876) something like 6 months ago, but since it has not yet been fixed I'm wondering whether there is a quick fix that I am missing.

I want to merge two graphs based on their names:

```
g1 = igraph.Graph()
g2 = igraph.Graph()

# add vertices
g1.add_vertices(["A","B"])
g2.add_vertices(["B","C","D"])

for vertex in g1.vs:
    print vertex.index
0
1

for vertex in g2.vs:
    print vertex.index
0
1
2
```

However when I perform the union, igraph uses the vertex IDs rather than the names, so I end up with three vertices instead of four (if it was based on names). I guess that because `B` has index `0` in `g2`, it is merged with `A` of `g1`. And in a similar way, `C` of `g2` is merged with `B` of `g1`.

```
g_union = igraph.Graph.union(g1,g2)

g_union.vs['name'] # of course
KeyError: 'Attribute does not exist'

for vertex in g_union.vs:
    print vertex.index
0
1
2
```

Any idea on how to bypass this issue? This is possible, since it was done in the R implementation of igraph.

Comment: Union by name is not supported yet in igraph (unless you are willing to code it yourself). The C core itself does not support unions based on vertex attributes. The R version supports it because someone has written a function for it in pure R. Unfortunately I have very little time to devote to igraph recently, so I'm afraid that you'll have to come up with a similar function yourself in Python.

Comment: @Tamás thanks for the candid answer. I'll try to see if I can reproduce the R function in Python, and keep you posted if positive.

Comment: @Tamás I can't find that R function you're referring to on github. Would you be kind enough for pointing me to it? Thanks for your time

Comment: All the graph operators in R-igraph (union, intersection etc) are here: https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/blob/dev/R/operators.R . They perform the operation using vertex names (instead of IDs) if @byname=TRUE@.

Comment: @Tamás Thanks, I knew that, the problem is that I can't get my hands on the R source code. When I type `getAnywhere(union.igraph)`, all I get is 
`A single object matching ‘union.igraph’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for union from namespace igraph
  namespace:igraph
with value

function (..., byname = "auto") 
{
    .igraph.graph.union.or.intersection("R_igraph_union", ..., 
        byname = byname, keep.all.vertices = TRUE)
}
<environment: namespace:igraph>`

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a new graph, and add vertices by name. Of course, this would eliminate other node properties, which you would also have to add manually.

```
g1 = igraph.Graph()
g2 = igraph.Graph()

# add vertices
g1.add_vertices(["A","B"])
g2.add_vertices(["B","C","D"])

g3 = igraph.Graph()
verts_to_add = []
for v in g1.vs:
    if v['name'] not in verts_to_add:
        verts_to_add.append(v['name'])
for v in g2.vs:
    if v['name'] not in verts_to_add:
        verts_to_add.append(v['name'])

g3.add_vertices(verts_to_add)

for v in g3.vs:
    print(v['name'])

#A
#B
#C
#D
```