# python igraph, graph intersection/union based on vertex names/labels

Tags: python, graph, igraph, intersection

I´m pretty new to Python and igraph especially. For my Bachelor thesis i have to compare graphs and therefor to determine the graph intersection and union. I tried the following:

```
from igraph import *
import json

with open('test_graphs.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

test1 = data['test1']
test2 = data['test2']

t1 = Graph(directed=True)
for v in test1:
    t1.add_vertex(v)
for v in test1:
    for o in test1[v]:
        t1.add_edge(v, o)
print(t1)

t2 = Graph(directed=True)
for v in test2:
    t2.add_vertex(v)
for v in test2:
    for o in test2[v]:
        t2.add_edge(v, o)

print(t2)

gr = t1.intersection(t2)
print(gr)
```

Where my json file is as follows:

```
{
    "test1" : {
        "A": ["B","C"],
        "B": [],
        "C": []
    },

    "test2" : {
        "A": ["B","D"],
        "B": [],
        "D": []
    }
}
```

I expected to be the output of the intersection to be A->B. But instead the following out put came up:

```
IGRAPH DN-- 3 2 --
+ attr: name (v)
+ edges (vertex names):
A->B, A->C
IGRAPH DN-- 3 2 --
+ attr: name (v)
+ edges (vertex names):
A->B, A->D
IGRAPH D--- 3 2 --
+ edges:
2->0 2->1
```

The first both printed graphs show, that the both input graphs work as expected (even tough I don´t understand where the 'attr' came from?).
But the output graph doesn´t consider that vertex A and B in both my graphs are identical while C and D are. So my question: How can I determine the intersection (and analog the union) of the graph, considering my labels for the vertices.

Comment: check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182255/perform-union-of-graphs-based-on-vertex-names-python-igraph

Answer (score 2):

In the question [Perform union of graphs based on vertex names Python igraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182255/perform-union-of-graphs-based-on-vertex-names-python-igraph) linked by paqmo, the maintainer says that this functionality (unions or intersections by vertex name) is not available in python-igraph. So you will have to write functions to do it yourself.

Here is one approach for the union. Add isolated vertices to both graphs, so that they both have the same set of vertex names, and then permute both their sets of vertices so that the names come in the same order. Then the standard `union` method (equivalently, the `|` operator) will do the right thing. Unfortunately, the `union` method does not maintain attributes, so you have to add back the names, and any other attributes that you need.

```
def named_union(graph1, graph2):
    A = graph1.copy()
    B = graph2.copy() # so added vertices don't affect original graphs
    Anams = set(A.vs['name'])
    Bnams = set(B.vs['name'])
    A.add_vertices(list(Bnams - Anams))
    B.add_vertices(list(Anams - Bnams))
    nams = sorted(Anams | Bnams)
    Aind = [nams.index(nm) for nm in A.vs['name']]
    Bind = [nams.index(nm) for nm in B.vs['name']]
    A = A.permute_vertices(Aind) # permute vertices to come in same order as in nams
    B = B.permute_vertices(Bind) # ditto
    Z = A | B
    Z.vs['name'] = nams
    return Z
```

We can do something similar for intersections, except that we remove vertices from each graph which aren't in the other, then permute the remaining vertices to come in the same order in both graphs, before using the standard `intersection` method (or `&` operator).

```
def named_intersect(graph1, graph2):
    A = graph1.copy()
    B = graph2.copy() # so removed vertices don't affect original graphs
    Anams = set(A.vs['name'])
    Bnams = set(B.vs['name'])
    A.delete_vertices(Anams - Bnams)
    B.delete_vertices(Bnams - Anams)
    nams = sorted(Anams & Bnams)
    Aind = [nams.index(nm) for nm in A.vs['name']]
    Bind = [nams.index(nm) for nm in B.vs['name']]
    A = A.permute_vertices(Aind)
    B = B.permute_vertices(Bind)
    Z = A & B
    Z.vs['name'] = nams
    return Z
```

Trivia: `delete_vertices` does the right thing when given a set, but `add_vertices` does not, unless we turn the set into a list first. A set with, say, two elements 'A' and 'B' results in adding two vertices, both named `{'A', 'B'}`—this seems like a bug.